# Is it possible to embed the sidebar with Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

We'd like to use Google Maps to keep track of local garage sales. We've created a map ([see here](http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?msa=0&msid=112102903815208037078.00046b7738708093a5ad7&cd=2&hl=en&ie=UTF8&ll=44.245691,-86.240616&spn=0.287749,0.504684&z=11)) and we'd like to embed that map on our website. However, when we do, we lose the sidebar of the map that contains a list of all the garage sales.

We're quite familiar with how to embed a Google; they've made the process quite simple. However, is there a way that we can embed the map and keep the sidebar list of garage sales?

Answer (score 4):

To my knowledge, the best way would be to create your own container of the sales and link them to a map you are populating.  I am assuming you are building and entering your data on Google's site and using the embed feature, which means my answers is significantly more work.

You would need to have your down data source and use the Maps API to create a map and a sidebar.

Your woudln't be using the iFrame anymore, you would be coding your own solution.  If you have done JavaScript before, it is really fairly easy, if you haven't there are some good examples.

Answer (score 2):

this tutorial  http://econym.org.uk/gmap/basic2.htm  shows exactly how to do it and supplies the code (which i reproduce by kind permission of the authors: Community Church Javascript Team http://www.bisphamchurch.org.uk)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Google Maps</title>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=false&amp;key=ABQIAAAAPDUET0Qt7p2VcSk6JNU1sBSM5jMcmVqUpI7aqV44cW1cEECiThQYkcZUPRJn9vy_TWxWvuLoOfSFBw" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body onunload="GUnload()">


    <!-- you can use tables or divs for the overall layout -->

    <table border=1>
      <tr>
        <td>
           <div id="map" style="width: 550px; height: 450px"></div>
        </td>
        <td width = 150 valign="top" style="text-decoration: underline; color: #4444ff;">
           <div id="side_bar"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>

    </table>
    <a href="basic2.htm">Back to the tutorial page</a>


    <noscript><b>JavaScript must be enabled in order for you to use Google Maps.</b> 
      However, it seems JavaScript is either disabled or not supported by your browser. 
      To view Google Maps, enable JavaScript by changing your browser options, and then 
      try again.
    </noscript>


    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[

    if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {

      // this variable will collect the html which will eventually be placed in the side_bar
      var side_bar_html = "";

      // arrays to hold copies of the markers and html used by the side_bar
      // because the function closure trick doesnt work there
      var gmarkers = [];


      // A function to create the marker and set up the event window
      function createMarker(point,name,html) {
        var marker = new GMarker(point);
        GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
          marker.openInfoWindowHtml(html);
        });
        // save the info we need to use later for the side_bar
        gmarkers.push(marker);
        // add a line to the side_bar html
        side_bar_html += '<a href="javascript:myclick(' + (gmarkers.length-1) + ')">' + name + '<\/a><br>';
         return marker;
      }


      // This function picks up the click and opens the corresponding info window
      function myclick(i) {
        GEvent.trigger(gmarkers[i], "click");
      }


      // create the map
      var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
      map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());
      map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
      map.setCenter(new GLatLng( 43.907787,-79.359741), 8);

      // add the points    
      var point = new GLatLng(43.65654,-79.90138);
      var marker = createMarker(point,"This place","Some stuff to display in the<br>First Info Window")
      map.addOverlay(marker);

      var point = new GLatLng(43.91892,-78.89231);
      var marker = createMarker(point,"That place","Some stuff to display in the<br>Second Info Window")
      map.addOverlay(marker);

      var point = new GLatLng(43.82589,-78.89231);
      var marker = createMarker(point,"The other place","Some stuff to display in the<br>Third Info Window")
      map.addOverlay(marker);


      // put the assembled side_bar_html contents into the side_bar div
      document.getElementById("side_bar").innerHTML = side_bar_html;

    }

    else {
      alert("Sorry, the Google Maps API is not compatible with this browser");
    }

    // This Javascript is based on code provided by the
    // Community Church Javascript Team
    // http://www.bisphamchurch.org.uk/   
    // http://econym.org.uk/gmap/

    //]]>
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm well into accessing the Google Maps API v3 with Javascript, and I've experimented successfully with a lot of different sample scripts, but I've come to the conclusion that the best (and quickest) method for producing embedded maps - with sidebars and lots of other options - is to go to http://www.mymapsplus.com/AddMyMap (thanks Chris B), and make a £10 donation to get rid of the adverts in generated maps - see e.g. http://www.hope-projects.org.uk/node/41. Their Edit page allows you to add or change almost any option you could think of with a few clicks.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do requires use of the MAPS API but it's not very hard if you know some javascript. Essentially, load the datapoints into a Javascript array, plot them on the map and then populate your html with the array information.

This link is a page I recently wrote that does the above and also dynamically repopulates the array from the db as the user drags the map (hardly any CSS at present either).

[map with dynamic links](http://ec2-72-44-61-143.compute-1.amazonaws.com/map.html?s=8&lt=-19.2584&lg=146.8005)

Happy to answer any more comments.

P.S. Cool map icon!

Tim

Answer (score 0):

I found one site that will generate your map with a sidebar, but if you want more control, you'll need to create your own map, as the others have suggested.

[http://www.mymapsplus.com/AddMyMap](http://www.mymapsplus.com/AddMyMap/)

http://www.mapchannels.com/

Answer (score 0):

Another site that will generate your map with a sidebar is [mapalist.com](http://mapalist.com/).