# How do I add side navigation to Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

When I create a Google Map and Share it, to the left, there is a list of links to locations on that map. I would like to be able to add that list of links next to the embedded map in a web page. See example: http://aquascapedesigns.com/index.php/pond-tours/saint-charles-illinois-anytime-pond-tour

I have the map in place. I just need to figure know how to add the links to the side.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this question:

[Is it possible to embed the sidebar with Google Maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050533/is-it-possible-to-embed-the-sidebar-with-google-maps)

Comment: Hi Chris. Perfect. Thank you for the link.